# Openldap. How to add and then re-read new attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have custom schema in my ldap customContact.schema with 5 attributes

Now I need to add one more attribute:

```
# localID
attributetype ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.36
    NAME 'localID'
    DESC 'Local account ID'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

So I added it to my schema file and restarted openldap service. But still getting:

```
conn=1006 op=1 RESULT tag=105 err=17 text=localID: attribute type undefined
```

How to re-read schema file so that new attribute became available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Many infos you find on OpenLDAP and its configuration is outdated. In modern installations, you don't edit schema or config files but have to use the online configuration method and connect to the `cn=config` subtree and add the informations there. See the [official doc](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) for more infos.

Comment: I created .ldif file , but now getting "modifying entry "cn={12}customContact"
ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
additional info: no global superior knowledge"